# Why am I getting multiple detection boxes on an image?

Tags: tensorflow, object, detection

Hello I'm new to the object detection tensorflow area. I tagged my images with the labelimg program and then trained them, but among the results I got, I got multiple detections on an object. What can I do to prevent this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZqKY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal you get multiple detections with different score. Post process your result: use some score threshold, merge your detections if they are at the same position. Check out this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-part1-4dbe5147ad0a)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I don't know what is 
 first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 
and what does second_stage_post_processing do?

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: nms - Non-Max Suppression; iou - Intersection over Union. Regarding second_stage_post_processing - cant guess without context, provide some please.